# Wifi problem with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, tp-link

Can't connect to wifi. I'm using the TP-Link Archer a4u usb to connect, which I think I installed correctly because I do see my SSID. However, every time I connect to it, it fails and asks for password again. I added the lines

```
[device] 
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

to

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

as was suggested in other posts. However, no luck. [This link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25418484/) hopefully provides sufficient information. I suspect it has something to do with `dmesg` output which is along the lines of: `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx18d6c70b5053: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The correct wording is:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

And not `=0`. Please change the file and restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```